# Summing values from a text file in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, sum, text-files

I am writing a Visual Basic program that reads information for a file named profit.txt. My form has a menu strip which is set up like this File->Open File->Exit

The portion of the program that I am stuck on right now is this:

When the user selects File->Open File, an open file dialog appears. If the user selects anything besides profit.txt, a message box appears telling them that they cannot use that file and nothing else is done. If the user does select profit.txt, then sum all the values in that file, but do not display the sum yet.

Thanks to the help below I can get the file to open, but do not know how to get the sum of all the elements in the file. The sum isn't actually shown until the user clicks certain radio buttons and check boxes and inputs amount in text boxes. The program then uses the information from the user to get the final profit by subtracting the amounts given from the sum of the values in the file.

Here's my most recent code.

```
    Option Strict On

    Imports System.IO

    Public Class Form1

           Private Sub menOpen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles menOpen.Click
        Dim ofd As New OpenFileDialog
        ofd.Filter = "text files |*.txt|All Files|*.*"
        ofd.InitialDirectory =   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)

         If ofd.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim selectedFileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ofd.FileName)
            If selectedFileName.ToLower = "profit.txt" Then
                Dim line As String
                Using reader As New StreamReader(ofd.OpenFile)
                    While Not reader.EndOfStream
                        line = reader.ReadLine
                        Console.WriteLine(line)
                    End While
                End Using
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("You cannot use that file!")
            End If
        End If
   End Sub

    Private Sub menExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles menExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are always opening the same file, why make the user have to choose it?  Try looping through your file with `For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines(menOpen.FileName)` instead.

Comment: (But use `File.ReadLines` instead; it’s a generator that only reads one line at a time.)

Comment: For the desktop directory, set the following property: `menOpen.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)` before you call ShowDialog().

Comment: @LarsTech, I wondered that myself, but since it's for a class I guess I should probably stick to the instructions we were given. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make your OpenFileDialog have the same name as your Menu.  You can use System.IO.Path.GetFileName() to retrieve just the filename portion (no path).  Then compare that against your hard-coded value:

```
Private Sub menOpen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles menOpen.Click
    Dim OFD As New OpenFileDialog
    OFD.Filter = "text files |*.txt|All Files|*.*"
    If OFD.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim selectedFileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(OFD.FileName)
        If selectedFileName.ToLower = "profit.txt" Then
            Dim line As String
            Using reader As New StreamReader(OFD.OpenFile)
                While Not reader.EndOfStream
                    line = reader.ReadLine
                    Console.WriteLine(line)
                End While
            End Using
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("You cannot use that file!")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Here's a simple example of converting the string in `line` to a numeric value using Integer.Parse():

```
    Dim value As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(line, value) Then
        total = total + value
    End If
```

Obviously you'd have to do this for each "line" in the file, so this should be happening **inside** the `While` loop.  You need to declare the `total` variable outside the loop (and the using statement), and don't forget to output that total somewhere.

Comment: Good catch on the variable name.

Comment: Thank you so much! Any suggestions on how to get the program to get the sum of the values in the text file?

Comment: Use Integer.Parse() to convert each line value into a numeric value.  Declare a variable to hold the sum, **outside** the loop, and accumulate the values as you convert them.

Comment: Can you tell me where in the code I should insert the Integer.Parse()? I've never actually used that before, so am not sure how it works.